# Database table design control

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

Is there a control in the .NET WinForm library for database design similar to the control found in the Create View dialog of SQL Management Studio.  A control that displays multiple tables floating within a background and allows lines to be drawn between specific fields?  Something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no control that does all of what you want combined into one pre-existing control.  That's what user controls are for--you can aggregate a bunch of other controls into a user control and then treat it as a unit.